# My UIElements are not showing after I set gradient to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

i set my view to have a gradient background with this code

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.2836692631, blue: 0.456893146, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 237/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]
        view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

But when i do that , all my other elements like `UIButton` and `UILabels` will not appear. how can i solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert it as a sublayer.

Check my UIView's Extension.

```
extension UIView {
  func setGradientBackgroundColor(colorOne: UIColor, colorTow: UIColor) {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTow.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
  }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
myview.setGradientBackgroundColor(colorOne: firstColor, colorTow: secondColor])
```

Answer (score 0):

@KHY.

You need to just change 1 thing in your code։

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

gradientLayer.frame = viewMy.boundsgradientLayer.colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.2836692631, blue: 0.456893146, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 237/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]

//use below code instead of `"view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)"`

viewMy.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```